# Merge two array using ratio wise in java

Tags: java, arrays, list, linked-list

I have two array like this.

```
String[] arr1 = {"11","22","33","44","55","66","77"};
String[] arr2 = {"111","222","333","444","555","666","777","888","999"};
```

I want to merge these two array using combination of index value.

My input will be two integer value (2:3 ratio), like this

```
int firstArray = 2;    //input value
int secondArray = 3;   //input value
```

After merge all value will be stored in single list.
Now i need output like this.

```
11
22
111
222
333
33
44
444
555
666
55
66
777
888
999
77
```

Input value should increase next time this loop execute on next time.

So second time when calling the for loop input value (3:4 ratio) should be like this.

```
int firstArray = 3; 
int secondArray = 4;
```

Second Time Output:

```
11
22
33
111
222
333
444
44
55
66
555
666
777
888
77
999
```

I tried using for loop and circular linked list. I couldn't able to do proper functionality for this.
Can anybody give suggestion to build a proper functionality.

Here is my code what i tried.

```
String[] arr1 = {"11","22","33","44","55","66","77"};
String[] arr2 = {"111","222","333","444","555","666","777","888","999"};

int f = 2;

for(int i=0;i<arr1.length;i++){

    if(i == f){             
        f = f+f;    

        int s = 3;      
        for(int j=0;j<arr2.length ;j++){

            if(j == s){                             
                s = s+s;
            }

            if(j < s)
                System.out.println(arr2[j]);                        

        }

    }

    if(i < f)
        System.out.println(arr1[i]);

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Circular Linked List and using for loop but i couldn't finish my function without error.

Comment: please add your code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try that:

```
private static String[] mergeArrays(String[] arr1, String[] arr2, int firstArray, int secondArray) {
    final String[] ret = new String[arr1.length + arr2.length];

    for (int j = 0, k = 0; j < arr1.length || k < arr2.length;) {
        while (j < arr1.length) {
            ret[j + k] = arr1[j];
            if (++j % firstArray == 0)
                break;
        }
        while (k < arr2.length) {
            ret[j + k] = arr2[k];
            if (++k % secondArray == 0)
                break;
        }
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Here is how to call it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] arr1 = { "11", "22", "33", "44", "55", "66", "77" };
    String[] arr2 = { "111", "222", "333", "444", "555", "666", "777", "888", "999" };

    String[] arr = mergeArrays(arr1, arr2, 2, 3);

    System.out.println("Ratio 2:3");

    for (String str : arr) {
        System.out.println(str);
    }

    arr = mergeArrays(arr1, arr2, 3, 4);

    System.out.println("Ratio 3:4");

    for (String str : arr) {
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Florent Bayle, i have another question from same cocept. I tried from your solution from this post but i cant able to bring output can you check my [quesiton](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27860900/2189457).