# Dynamic array merge in java

Tags: java, arrays, list, sorting, linked-list

I have two array like this.

```
String[] arr1 = { "1", "2", "3" };
String[] arr2 = { "111", "222", "333", "444", "555", "666", "777", "888", "999" };
```

I want to merge these two array using combination of index value.

My input will be two integer value (2:3 ratio), like this

```
int firstArray = 2;    //input value
int secondArray = 4;   //input value
```

After merge all value will be stored in single list. Now i need output like this.

```
 1
 2
 111
 222
 333
 444
 3
 1
 555
 666
 777
 888
 2
 3    
 999
 111
 222
 333
```

loop should run till which array length is big and retrive all values from both array.

if array length got changed then output ratio also should change

```
String[] arr1 = { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8" };
String[] arr2 = { "111", "222", "333", "444", "555" };

int firstArray = 3;    //input value
int secondArray = 2;   //input value
```

output :

```
1
2
3
111
222
4
5
6
333
444
7
8
1
555
111
```

so condition is output should contain all values from both array and till maximum length of array and output should completed with second ratio(second input value - secondArray).

thanks in advance.

```
String[] arr = mergeArrays(arr1, arr2, 2, 3);

        System.out.println("Ratio 2:3");

        for (String str : arr) {
            System.out.println(str);
        }

private static String[] mergeArrays(String[] arr1, String[] arr2, int firstArray, int secondArray) {
        final String[] ret = new String[arr1.length + arr2.length];

        for (int j = 0, k = 0; j < arr1.length || k < arr2.length;) {
            if (j < arr1.length) {
                do {
                    ret[j + k] = arr1[j];
                    j++;
                } while (j < arr1.length && (j % firstArray != 0 || k == arr2.length));
            }
            if (k < arr2.length) {
                do {
                    ret[j + k] = arr2[k];
                    k++;
                } while (k < arr2.length && (k % secondArray != 0 || j == arr1.length));
            }
        }

        return ret;
    }
```

I tried from this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27836847/2189457)

but i cant able to bring correct out put

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used `List` instead of arrays, because I don't think you can really predict the length of the resulting array.

```
public static <T> List<T> merge(List<T> l1, List<T> l2, int r1, int r2) {
    List<T> result = new ArrayList<T>();

    int index1 = 0;
    int index2 = 0;

    while (index1 < l1.size() || index2 < l2.size()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < r1; ++i)
            result.add(l1.get((index1 + i) % l1.size()));
        index1 += r1;
        if (index2 < l2.size()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < r2; ++i)
                result.add(l2.get((index2 + i) % l2.size()));
            index2 += r2;
        }

    }
    return result;
}
```

Test code:

```
String[] arr1 = { "1", "2", "3" };
String[] arr2 = { "111", "222", "333", "444", "555", "666", "777",
            "888", "999" };

System.out.println(merge(Arrays.asList(arr1), Arrays.asList(arr2), 2, 4));
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 111, 222, 333, 444, 3, 1, 555, 666, 777, 888, 2, 3, 999, 111, 222, 333]
```

Comment: Hi Niels, Thanks for support.Your output is almost correct but one logic is missing output will be end with second ratio(sencondArray).

Comment: Hi Neils, after remove **if (index2 < l2.size())** from your code i am getting the output what i expected

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    int[] array1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
    int[] array2 = {11, 22, 33};

    int firstArray = 3;
    int secondArray = 5;

    for (int a1 = 0, a2 = 0; ;) {
        for (int i = 0; i < firstArray; i++)
            System.out.println(array1[a1++ % array1.length]);
        if (a1 >= array1.length && a2 >= array2.length)
            break;
        for (int i = 0; i < secondArray; i++)
            System.out.println(array2[a2++ % array2.length]);
        if (a1 >= array1.length && a2 >= array2.length)
            break;
    }
}
```

If you want to generate a new array instaed of print result on video, simply declare an `ArrayList` and add elements to it using the `add()` method:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    int[] array1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
    int[] array2 = {11, 22, 33};

    int firstArray = 3;
    int secondArray = 5;

    ArrayList<Integer> output = new ArrayList();

    for (int a1 = 0, a2 = 0; ;) {
        for (int i = 0; i < firstArray; i++)
            output.add(array1[a1++ % array1.length]);
        if (a1 >= array1.length && a2 >= array2.length)
            break;
        for (int i = 0; i < secondArray; i++)
            output.add(array2[a2++ % array2.length]);
        if (a1 >= array1.length && a2 >= array2.length)
            break;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < output.size(); i++)
        System.out.println(output.get(i));
}
```

If you want to create a function:

```
public ArrayList<Integer> merge(int[] array1, int[] array2, int firstArray, int secondArray) {

    ArrayList<Integer> output = new ArrayList();

    for (int a1 = 0, a2 = 0; ;) {
        for (int i = 0; i < firstArray; i++)
            output.add(array1[a1++ % array1.length]);
        if (a1 >= array1.length && a2 >= array2.length)
            break;
        for (int i = 0; i < secondArray; i++)
            output.add(array2[a2++ % array2.length]);
        if (a1 >= array1.length && a2 >= array2.length)
            break;
    }

    return output;
}
```

If you don't want to return an `ArrayList`, simply convert it to an `int[]`

Comment: Hi Giulio, thanks for support. Your output is almost correct but one logic is missing output will be end with second ratio(sencondArray).

Comment: I don't understand, try to explain better what's the problem.